# Tracking the Segmentation in Solr

Tags: java, lucene, solr

In my application i am adding all the docid in the hash map. But while segmentation happen then docid are getting change... Is there any possibility to track the segmentation ?Because i am having one own function which will recreate hash map according to docids?

now on each commit i am recreating my hash map. so that if i found when segmentation is happen . then i can recreate hash map when segmentation is happened..

So please help me...  i am not getting any idea for this...
Example :
Docid    SEQID
1201     4522
1202     4576
1203     4567

Docid are from lucene ... my need is when segmentation is happen then i need to call my recreatHashMap() so can anyone tell me when Segmentation is called. where i need to keep track.

Advance thanks.

Comment: I dont get it. What segmentation are you talking about? Do you post documents to solr with a unique document id defined in your schema.xml and when the document is returned by a search result the documentid has changed? Maybe you will clarify your question a little...

Comment: yes when we post document.. there will be some delete docid which i will be alloated for new document.. so docid getting changed

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not delete the ids from the hashmap when you delete documents from the index?

Comment: when i delete doc from index with unique id which i added.. at the time of deleteing we cant know docid ..

Comment: Why not? Create one while indexing. E.g. a counter of type long and put it to your document. - Or before I think in the wrong direction. You do not allow your user to delete some documents by query, or do you? You delete by the documents id?

Comment: sry here the problem is docid's are getting updated.And now i m creating the recreating the map for each commit.. i think that will not be good . for better performence

Comment: are you talking about Lucene DocIds or your own defined document IDs?

Comment: Lucene Docid ... my need is when segmentation is happen then i need to call my recreatHashMap()

Comment: @Syed: could you tell us why you're messing with Lucene DocIds in Solr? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the single entries from the hashmap, too, to add them with the updated document ids again.

Maybe you have to use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://cs.rocky.edu/java/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to prevent concurrent modification.